# NGINX subdirectory wordpress and symfony application

Tags: php, wordpress, symfony, nginx

I want to run both WordPress and Symfony instances in my Nginx configuration.

Symfony and WordPress are located as subdirectories of my root directory:

`Symfony: /var/www/mysite/pm/public`

`WordPress: /var/www/mysite/blog`

As soon as I extend the root directory in the server block to include "/pm/public", I am able to access my Symfony application. However, I would like to keep the root directory as specified above and have my Symfony application accessible at `/pm/public`. The same applies to WordPress, where I would like to set, for example, `/blog`.

Is there a way to configure Nginx to achieve this?

```
upstream php8.1-fpm {
    server unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock max_fails=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite;
    root /var/www/mysite;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location / {
        return 410; # Ressource nicht vorhanden
    }

    if (!-d $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    # Symfony
    location ^~ /pm {
        index index.php index.html;
        root /var/www/mysite/pm/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @pm;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/symfony_error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/symfony_access.log;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        }
    }

    location @pm {
        rewrite ^/pm/(.*)$ /pm/index.php last;
    }

    # Wordpress
    location /blog {
        index index.php index.html;
        alias /var/www/mysite/blog;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @blog;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/wordpress_error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/wordpress_access.log;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        }
    }
}
```

As reference is my apache2 config below, where my desired behaviour is working like a charm.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mysite
    ServerAlias www.mysite
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite/chain.pem

    <Directory /var/www/mysite/>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /blog /var/www/mysite/blog
    <Directory /var/www/mysite/blog>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /suitecrm /var/www/mysite/suitecrm/public
    <Directory /var/www/mysite/suitecrm/public>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    SSLProxyEngine on

    <Location /pm>
        ProxyPass https://mysite:8443/pm
        ProxyPassReverse https://mysite:8443/pm
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are aware that the `public/` directory of a symfony application should be the document root of the vhost right? Your composer.json, cache files, etc. are exposed on the internet.

Why not move the `blog/` directory inside the `public/` directory. Change the `root` to symfony `public/` directory. Add the `blog/` directory to your `.gitignore`, and you're done.

We have a similar situation, but the blog is located on a different server. We use nginx as a reverse proxy to proxy all `/blog(/|$)` urls to something else.

Comment: Hi Leroy. No I wasn't aware that symfony should be the document root. Do you have any resource for me, where this is stated? Thanks for your suggestion, I will pick it up today!

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html Read the section of "public directory". From there on you can put the `/public/blog/` in your .gitignore, and move your blog website in there. That's the easiest solution

Comment: Thanks for sharing the ressource. I already implemented it the way you suggested